# Lazy image load and CSS grid are not working together! Help me to find a solution

Tags: javascript, css, image, lazy-loading, css-grid

Hello fellow programmers,

For some time I'm learning front end, and at this moment I'm building mine portfolio. It is going well, but I encountered a problem with CSS grid and lazy load of images.

I'm using Intersection Observer to observe images and to load them from data-src. The problem arise when I come to section with images, only 1st row is loaded, and the other row doesn't get loaded at all, it's seems like it it's invisible to observer.

It looks like this:

[Problem with loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LELm5.jpg)

Code for CSS grid that I use is this one:

```
 display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(35rem, 1fr));
```

Code for JS lazy load:

```
const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");

const imgCallBack = (entries, observer) => {
  const [entry] = entries;
  if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;

  entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src;

  entry.target.addEventListener("load", () => {
    entry.target.classList.remove("blured");
  });

  observer.unobserve(entry.target);
};

const imgOptions = { root: null, threshold: 0, rootMargin: "900px" };

const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver(imgCallBack, imgOptions);

lazyImages.forEach((img) => imgObserver.observe(img));
```

When I turn off multiple columns, everything work as it should, but then I get to large section that it's not good. It's good for mobile phones, but not for desktop screens.

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ0VB.jpg)

So, my question is what can I do to make my other row is visible?
Thank you for consideration,
Aleksandar Đ.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can do it with html only now. [MDN - loading attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading), [support on CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr).

Comment: @AmauryHanser I'm not sure why, but when I do this, my images do not lazy load.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that the Intersection Observer is only observing the images that are initially visible in the viewport. As you scroll, new images come into view, (if you scroll back down than up , they will show up) but they are not being observed by the Intersection Observer because they are not initially visible. ( some expert can explain this further for us).

**You can use entries.forEach to handle multiple entries simultaneously.** This ensures that all the intersecting images are processed and loaded.

So your code will be :

```js
    const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");
    
    const imgCallBack = (entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
    
        entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src;
    
        entry.target.addEventListener("load", () => {
          entry.target.classList.remove("blured");
        });
    
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      });
    };
    
    const imgOptions = { root: null, threshold: 0, rootMargin: "900px" };
    
    const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver(imgCallBack, imgOptions);
    
    lazyImages.forEach((img) => imgObserver.observe(img));
```